# In regular expression or operator between 2 group is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create JavaScript regex expression of range **0 to 8759.59**

I have created 2 regex expression:
Below is my expression for this:

> Regex1

```
^([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|[1-7][0-9]{3}|8[0-6][0-9]{2}|87[0-5][0-9]|8759)(\.([0-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-9]))?$
```

And another expression for range 0 to 8758.99 not accept 8760,
Below is the expression for this:

> Regex2

```
^([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|[1-7][0-9]{3}|8[0-6][0-9]{2}|87[0-5][0-9]|8758)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Now when I try to put or operator between Regex2 and Regex1 then it not working as expectation.

I want it should accept value in range of 0-8759.59

Comment: Are you actually working with date/time strings?

Comment: Any reason you are trying to use RegExp only? This might be served better by parsing the string and doing a numeric check instead...

Comment: why are you not using comparison operator like <, > etc .. ?

Comment: Please provide sample input, desired output and current output. Show a little context code to help understanding the slightly quaint requirements.

Comment: Try to demonstrate what makes your think that the OR operator does not work.

Comment: @ChiragRavindra In my application pattern are used to check validation everywhere. So that's why I need regex only.

Comment: `regex` is not the right tool for the job. Write a simple `regex` that accepts numbers with two decimals then parse the recognized string to number and compare the number to the range limits you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Update As Per OP's Comment: ( [This will match anything less than
>   8759.60](https://regex101.com/r/xkTM8x/5/) )

```
^8759(\.[0-5]\d?)?$|^(87[0-5][0-8]|8[0-6]\d{2}|[0-7]\d{3}|\d{1,3})(\.\d\d?)?$
```

**Updated Code Snippet**

```js
    const regex = /^(87[0-5]\d|8[0-6]\d{2}|[0-7]\d{3}|\d{1,3})(\.[0-5]\d?)?$/;
    console.log(regex.test(`0`));
    console.log(regex.test(`8759.59`));
    console.log(regex.test(`8759.60`));
    console.log(regex.test(`10.59`));
    console.log(regex.test(`10.60`));
    console.log(regex.test(`8759`));
    console.log(regex.test(`876`));
    console.log(regex.test(`8761`));
    console.log(regex.test(`123.1`));
```

Explanation:

- `^` start of string
- `(87[0-5]\d|8[0-6]\d{2}|[0-7]\d{3}|\d{1,3})` 4 alternatives where -
- `87[0-5]\d`   87 followed by anything between 0-5 and then any digit
          `OR`

  `8[0-6]\d{2}` 8 followed by anything between 0-6 and the any two digit
  `OR`

  `[0-7]\d{3}` 0-7 followed by any 3 digits

  `OR`
- `\d{1,3}` any 1 to 3 digits

Comment: This is not exactly what i need as Your expression is not accepting 10.60 also. But I need expression which except every value smaller than or equal to 8759.59

Comment: !!!! you wrote in your question that : *I have created 2 regex expression one for 0 to 8759.59 except decimal upto .59 only like 10.59 is acceptable but 10.60 is not acceptable* . This is very strange !

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman As per my understanding simply she wants a regex that accept value between **0 to 8759.59**

Comment: @UmangPatwa why are you trying to guess where in the OP it is clearly written that 10.60 is not acceptable ? it should be edited there isn't it ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman I tested expression provided by OP. And she want or operator between **Regex2** and **Regex1** which means she want it should accept **10.60** or **10** any value less then 8759 but in case if value is **8759** then it should not accept  more then **.59** like **8759.99** is not acceptable but **8759.59** is acceptable

Comment: @UmangPatwa, Still the question needs to be edited.. you may edit that or she herself can do it... anyway... I have updated my answer

Comment: `1000.123` is obviously inside the `0..8759.99` range but it is not accepted by this `regex`.

Comment: @axiac did you see the attempt from the op which states : \d{1,2} in the end ?

Comment: The question reads *"I am trying to create JavaScript regex expression of range 0 to 8759.59"*. I didn't read the `regex`es posted in the question. The op already mentioned they didn't solve their problem. This is because regular expressions are not designed to validate a string against a range. This is the job of the [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: The question did not mention to not read anything beyond the line that you have mentioned... you may say the OP explicitly didn't write 2 digits... yet she put it in the regex... which I thought could be a starting point.... since her acceptance of the answer, I got the feeling that that is what she meant... isn't it ? So in my view, this is just an useless argument

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
^8759(?:\.[0-5]\d?)?$|^(?:(?:(?:|[1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-7]\d{2})\d|8[0-7][0-5][0-8])(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/104)

**Edited** because above regex missed the point which `8[0-7][0-5][0-8]` does not accept legitimate inputs, 8199, 8369, etc

```
^8759(?:\.[0-5]\d?)?$|^(?:(?:(?:|[1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-7]\d{2})\d|8(?:[0-6]\d{2}|7(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-8])))(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/105)

Changed part from  `8[0-7][0-5][0-8]`

```
8(?:[0-6]\d{2}|7(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-8]))
```

Comment: 8[0-7][0-5][0-8]   means 8169 is invalid

Answer (score 0):

The regular expressions **are not** the tool to verify if a number belongs to a certain range.
The **are** a good tool to check if a string is the text representation of a number, so let's use them for this purpose and let the comparison operators handle the range check:

```js
function validateNumber(input, min, max)
{
    const re = /^\d+(\.\d*)?$/

    if (re.exec(input)) {
       let nb = parseFloat(input)
       return min <= nb && nb <= max
    } else {
       return false
    }
}

console.log(validateNumber('8759.60', 0, 8759.59))
```

Comment: Your answer accepts invalid number format turn `\d*` into `\d+` then it will work

Comment: Neither it works for `console.log(validateNumber('8759.59999999999999999999999999999999999999999', 0, 8759.59))`

Comment: Please explain why `\d*` is not correct, in your opinion.

Comment: '\.\d* ' means `66.` is a valid number.. which it is not... assume this validator would be used when the user press keys... and the input value will directly be stored as string in the db... and as a presentational unit this is a bug

Comment: As long as we are discussing in English, `66.` is a perfectly valid representation of a number. Also `.66` is a perfectly valid number in English and it is (intentionally) not handled by my answer.

Comment: 8759.599999 is obviously less than 8759.60, so it should cover isn't it ? I am going by your logic actually

Comment: As long as we are discussing programming... and number validation, then `66.` aint a perfect number this is a client end bug...